# Combinatorics identity for arbitrary value of Spin

Tags: mathematical-physics, field-theory, higher-spin

I wanted to prove this identity for the general value of $\lambda$

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda-1} (-1)^n{\lambda-1 \choose n} {\partial^{\left(\lambda-1-n \right)}{\partial_-}^{\left(n \right)}}\left( \bar{\Phi}\; \partial_{-}^{\left(\lambda-n \right)} \partial^n \bar{\Phi} \right)\;=\;\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda-1} (-1)^n{\lambda-1 \choose n}\left(\partial^{\left(\lambda-1-n \right)}{\partial_-}^{\left(n \right)} \bar{\Phi}\; \partial_{-}^{\left(\lambda-n \right)} \partial^n \bar{\Phi} \right)
$$

where $\partial$ and $\partial_-$ are derivatives in light-cone coordinates and $\bar{\Phi}$ is superfield antisymmetric for odd value of $\lambda$

I have tried proving it by induction, I first showed it  equal for $\lambda=1,2,3$
Then I assumed it is true for $\lambda$ and tried for $\lambda+1$ but I couldn't prove it

I have also tried by taking LHS and moving the derivatives inside the bracket using Leibniz product rule

$(fg)^{\lambda}=\sum_{n=0}^{\lambda} {\lambda \choose n}  f^{\lambda-n}g^n$

But I get three summations and I don't understand how to proceed further

Any suggestion and help would be appreciated

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic it is not from any reference though but it is similar to the identity given in this reference on page 6, equation 3.11 https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(83)90141-4